# Issue with showing coupon code in admin grid

Tags: magento2, custom-options, magento2.4, custom-admin-grid

I am trying to add new functionality and need to show coupon code in the Orders grid. I was able to show the column in the grid but it is not showing the data.
I followed this link `https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-coupon-code-column-in-magento-2-order-grid/`
And at the end it requires running a MySQL command manually, if I do the same it does starts showing codes but without the query, it is not showing any data.
I want to show the coupon code in the admin grid immediately after the order is added.
Should I try to write an observer for success order and then run the query or any other option is available.

Answer (score 0):

Add in or add an InstallSchema.php from this path of your custom module:

> Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallSchema.php

https://pastebin.com/jgjfcUSL

Then after, you have to map the coupon_code column to sales_order column in your di.xml configuration:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="coupon_code" xsi:type="string">sales_order.coupon_code</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Then in your sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="coupon_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Coupon Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```